# MobileFirst Geo-trigger "dwellInside" callback not invoked

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime, mobilefirst-studio

I am working with the Mobile First Platform studio 7.1 and following the documentation on location services here [Documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/location-services-hybrid-applications/). I am doing all my testing with the Mobile Browser Simulator.

I have noticed that while testing with the MBS the callback functions for the sample (DwellInside) are not getting invoked. For example, the app says that an alert will displayed if the location has changed in the last 3 seconds.

[image]

I have created a sample application similar)to the one that can be downloaded from the "Documentation" link here:[MyCode](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0nwWJLn3Q9SbmgyU3Y0ZnNlQVE)

My version(which is just gets the locations and does a DwellInside) also cannot get the call back to be invoked.

Is there something that I am missing? Please advise.

Comment: Just FYI - going forward the Geolocation feature is not going to be supported/developed and you are advised to use 3rd party functionality that achieves the same... either the device native API or Cordova plug-ins, etc... as well as developing Cordova apps instead of Classic Hybrid apps.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thank you. I plan on taking the certification for 6.2 so I was going through all the documentation and tutorials as I would still need to know how these work

Comment: When using the MBS are you continuing to provide new locations? Or did you just set a starting location and not provide any new ones?

Comment: @user2674117 I did an acquirePosition and in the sucess callback I started a new acquisition that uses a DwellINside with passing the acquired longitude and latitude. I did not supply new coordinates

Comment: Ok, you will need to pass it new coordinates after startAcquisition. New triggers are evaluated the first time a new coordinate is supplied; it doesn't assume the last given position is necessarily current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not leave a question unanswered, as mentioned by @user2674117 in the comments:

> you will need to pass it new coordinates after `startAcquisition`. New triggers are evaluated the first time a new coordinate is supplied; it doesn't assume the last given position is necessarily current.